# Address Attribute not set to Address template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, address-attribute

I need to update default address layout which used in order, invoice and emails.
So that I change the layout in
**store->configuration->customer->customer configuration->address template.**

I need to display house number after the Street Name.
I created address attribute named as house_no. house_no value is available but is not showing email or PDF

this is the deafult

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

After the modification code

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend house_no}}<br/> {{var house_no}}{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

[image]

Please help me what is the wrong in there ?

Comment: You just removed this line `{{depend house_number_appendix}}<br/> {{var house_number_appendix}}{{/depend}}` in your modified code, anything alo changed, please let me know, are you getting any error please share ?

Comment: it was a mistake default code not containing house_no or house_number_appendix. I will update the question. any error not visible . i will attached screenshot also

Comment: If you have access to database related tables .. then see - customer_address_entity table is also not having house number or house number appendix. Please check at your side. and in address.phtml file in your vendor/magento folder - /app/design/frontend/Raptor/Desktop/Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard/address.phtml (this is my overridden path). We may need to create another table to hold extra information. I have customer_address_entity_extra_info and with inner join i am using but i don't know if the same case will work for you. Better to search if magento gives to add house number

Comment: Is these fields(house no and house no_appendix) in your form where customer is adding his address ? Are they storing properly which table or field please check with database also. This tutorial may be helpful - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Comment: house_no saved into database. when click edit button house no field is fill.
but unfortunately HTML address template not rending as I wish

Comment: which database table house_no is saving , may you please provide the table name with screenshot.

Comment: Hi problem was solved by  setup:di:compile command. This is am not use because the site is production environment.thanks everyone who support me

Comment: May you please upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will teach us to add the extra field in address form.
https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/add-custom-field-magento-2-shipping-address/

Please try the solution given here to add the fields house_no and house_number_appendix.